# dReal SMT solver counterexamples

Tags: smt, dreal

Does the dReal SMT solver return counterexamples?  I have seen examples where :produce-models is true, but I do not know how to generate counterexamples.  Also, the dReach tool has a --visualize option, so it would seem that dReal would need to produce some model information.  However, when I run it on .smt2 files, I can't seem to find a way to view counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

O.k., it is trivial :).  dReal does not follow the usual .smt2 convention of using (get-model), but you can get models by using the command line option --model.

E.g.: dReal --model microwave1.smt2